# php not setting infinite cookie

Tags: php, cookies

Ok, so now I have this code in my login form handler `.php` file:

```
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $db = "agendadb";
    $db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db);
  $res = $db->query("SELECT userId FROM tblUsers WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' AND password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
  if($res){
    if($row =  $res->fetch_assoc()){
      setcookie('userId', strval($row['userId']), 2147483647);
      $_COOKIE['userId']= $row['userId'];
      echo 1;
    }else{
      echo -2;
    }
  }else{
    echo -1;
  }
?>
```

Somewhy, the cookie `userId` is not being set, and I can't figure out why. The script is working because it echoes the result correctly, but the cookie is not being set and no errors are thrown.

In the begining of my index page I have the following code to check if the cookie has been set

```
<?php
echo '<script>';

if(!isset($_COOKIE['userId'])){
  echo 'console.log(" isset");';
}
if(empty($_COOKIE['userId'])){
  echo 'console.log(" empty");';
}
if($_COOKIE['userId']==""){
  echo 'console.log(" ==");';
}
echo '</script>';
?>
```

and after loging in my console in `index.php` always shows `isset empty ==`

Also, I tried using `ob_start();`  and `ob_end_flush();` in the login handler `.php` file, but did not work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why did you use if($res) ? also you have not mentioned the echo that you get from the first script

Comment: @georoot I use `if($res)` to check if the access to database was succesfull. What do you mean by the echo I get from the first script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few reasons why your cookie but not be being set.

#### Not accessible by the domain

Is it being set on the same directory as this script (are both your files in the exact same directory)? If not, then you need to specify the fourth parameter of the `cookie` to make it available to the whole domain, as well as fixing your parameters.

```
setcookie('userId', strval($row['userId']), time() + 2147483647, "/");
```

#### Stale cookie or wrong sub-domain

If your website is querying both `www` and `non-www` versions, then you may be getting different cookies because they are being treated as different sub-domains. You can change your `htaccess` to fix this, or you can check by going into your development console and typing `document.cookie` and comparing the two pages

#### Cookies aren't sent until second request or cache-related

Cookies are also not set on the first request on the script, as they only created once the request is finished. You should refresh the page again to make sure that's not happening. Your browser could also be caching and not getting the new cookie, it'd be best for you to clear all your cookies related to your test-site first before proceeding to fix your problem.

And also, an "infinite" cookie isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you man, I needed to add that fourth parameter because the script was in a different folder. That solved it.

Comment: About the infinite cookie, I know it is not possible, but setting it to 2038 year is as closest to infinite as I can get, I will certainly not be giving support to these guys after 23 years from now.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.